# How to filter data based on new and old data

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am new in angular. I have created an inline editable table that can perform CRUD operation inline.
The row which I am creating, I made its id with starting key `"a"` like this

```
 addNew(): void {
    this.data.push({
      id: "a" + this.newFieldCounter++,
      isEditable: true,
    });
  }
```

But user click on add button and when he want to cancel the operation, it should remove that new editable row, for that I have written like this:

```
cancel(data): void {
    this.data = this.data.filter((x) => !(x.id === data.id));
    data.isEditable = !data.isEditable;
}
```

The cancel button working fine for new rows, but when I am clicking on the edit button of the existing record and when I am clicking on the cancel button, that existing record is also getting removed from the table. :(
Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Could you please share your html file? This looks ok to me, maybe there is a problem in the html file.

Comment: @FilipCulig added html file...please check

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be, to give new entries a flag, that they are new. So when cancelling the editing, only those entries will be filtered out, that are new.

Therefore you could add `(blur)="removeNewFlag(data)"` or something like this to remove the flag on submission of your input.

You probably run into an issue, since clicking on the cancel button triggeres the blur event as well. So you can either delay the `removeNewFlag` method or you can change your code to only submit the input with a button (like the paperplane in messengers).

Check out this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-euxkvm?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Not able to understand anything

Comment: I added a stackblitz in order to show you, what I was talking about. Since you do not have mechanics to submit or save the changes you made to the item, you cannot really differenciate between "new" and "old" items. Therefore I added a save/submit functionality

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
addNew(): void {
    this.data.push({
      id: "a" + this.newFieldCounter++,
      isEditable: true,
      isNew: true  //for old entries it will be false or undefined
    });
  }

cancel(data): void {
    this.data = this.data.filter((x) => x.id !== data.id && !x.isNew);
    data.isEditable = !data.isEditable;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**
Store in an auxiliar obj the old data, and use a variable to know if is new or nor

```
onEdit(data)
{
   this.isNew=false;
   this.oldData={...data} //make a copy using spread operator
   ...
}
onAdd()
{
   this.isNew=true;
   ...
}
```

In cancel you can pass the index of the data

```
<i .... (click)="cancel(tableData,i)"></i>
```

and

```
cancel(data,index)
{
  if (this.isNew) //<--use the variable
    this.data = this.data.filter((x) => !(x.id === data.id));
  else
    this.tableData[index] ={...this.oldData}

  data.isEditable = !data.isEditable;
}
```

Comment: what is isNew in this?

Comment: Soryy, I confused with the response of Kshiti that add a new property:new when add the data. The "ideal" is that you use a simple variable, in edit you put the variable to false, in add you put the variable to true, and in cancel you "check" the value of the variable (And forget the if).  I just updating the anser (sorry the confusion)